# Using return value of _spawnl() to get PID?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, process

The documentation for the **_spawn** family of functions say they return a HANDLE when called with _P_NOWAIT.

I was hoping to use this handle with **TerminateProcess(h, 1);**

(In case the started process misbehaves.)

```
HANDLE h = (HANDLE) _spawnl(_P_NOWAIT, "C:\\temp\\hello.exe", NULL);
```

However, I don't understand the difference between these handles and the PID shown in the Task Manager.

The spawn function only ever returns very low values, like "248" and not what actually shows in Task Manager.

Can I use the return value of _spawn to kill a process and if so, how?

Comment: `GetProcessId()` may be what you need.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid

Comment: Don't forget to close the handle when done

Comment: Why do you need a (useless) process ID when you already hold a (useful) handle to it? If you're doing it the Linux/POSIX way, chances are that you're writing code that's below standard.

Comment: @I needed it to kill a process tree... feel free to educate me how to kill a process tree with HANDLEs, I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
auto process_handle = (HANDLE)_wspawnv(_P_NOWAIT, argv[1], &argv[1]);
auto procID = GetProcessId(ID);
```

<sub>thanks [sj95126](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13843268/sj95126)</sub>